# Selecting Rows within Separate IDs until a first occurrence of given value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I am try to get all rows within each separate ID until the first occurrence of a given value, in this case "CR" but have to reverse the order of the rows. Here is how the data is stored on the table:

```
ID    DebtMth    YearMth    Status   Balance
1         5      2015-02      DR      10.00
1         4      2015-03      DR      10.00
1         3      2015-04      CR      00.00
1         2      2015-06      DR      10.00
1         1      2015-07      DR      10.00
2        10      2011-01      DR      20.00
2         9      2011-02      DR      20.00
2         8      2011-03      CR      20.00
3        11      2012-02      DR      30.00
3        10      2012-03      DR      30.00
3         8      2012-05      CR      00.00
3         7      2012-06      CR      00.00
3         6      2012-07      DR      30.00
```

I need to reverse the order so the last row within each ID group becomes the first and so on. So the table would be sorted as follows.

```
ID    DebtMth    YearMth    Status   Balance
1         1      2015-07      DR      10.00
1         2      2015-06      DR      10.00
1         3      2015-04      CR      00.00
1         4      2015-03      DR      10.00
1         5      2015-02      DR      10.00
2         8      2011-03      CR      20.00
2         9      2011-02      DR      20.00
2        10      2011-01      DR      20.00
3         6      2012-07      DR      30.00
3         7      2012-06      CR      00.00
3         8      2012-05      CR      00.00
3        10      2012-03      DR      30.00
3        11      2012-02      DR      30.00
```

Now I need to select rows within each ID group up until the Status is 'CR' and exclude any ID whose first row is 'CR'. So the output would look like this.

```
ID    DebtMth    YearMth    Status   Balance
1         1      2015-07      DR      10.00
1         2      2015-06      DR      10.00
3         6      2012-07      DR      30.00
```

I am using the Query Designer in Report Builder 3 connecting to an Microsoft SQL2012 Server.

I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    id , DebtMth , YearMth , Status , Balance 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *
        , MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'CR' THEN YearMth END) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS first_cr_yearMth
    FROM YourTable
) AS T
WHERE YearMth > first_cr_yearMth OR first_cr_yearMth IS NULL
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for all your replies and have used the answer from Nikolay and it works a treat. Thanks again Martin

Comment: Hi, Martin. Could you mark my replies as right reply?

Comment: Hi Nikolay, Sure thing. M